# Cloud Control Autoscaling

Tags: cloudcontrol

I could not find that much on auto scaling, at the CloudControl docs, only some old blog posts. I am interested in autoscaling as my particular app is for consumers who will not be using it during the work day, they will be using it early mornings and late evenings primarily. I would like to then use autoscaling, so that I can put a limit on the amount of Ram at say X gigs, and when needed that much RAM is provisioned, and when not we scale down to 1MEH.

Is this still supported, and where are the docs? 
Also, what is the performance impact, say there are no users at 4am and then they start pouring on, the scaling will take place in good time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no auto-scaling built into cloudControl applications any more.

If you want this, you will have to build something yourself. For example with a cronjob that does up/downscaling depending on the time.

Comment: Instead of just time based, you can also use calls to the REST API to scale up or down based on metrics inside your application.